# Skip form validation on command button

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a JSF page that includes a tree form tag which is rendered depending on some bean property. There are two buttons for next and previous page. I want to skip form validation on the button which goes to the previous page.

I tried the following ways to disable the validation:

- Set `h:commandButton immediate="true"`
- Change button by `a4j:commandButton ajaxSingle="true" rerender="someparts"`

It does not work. Why does the navigation fail when I want to skip validation?

Comment: please post your code (jsp file etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`immediate="true"` does skip the validation. Make sure you have redeployed successfully, and the there aren't any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem using `a4j:commandButton ajaxSingle="true" reRender=":outhercomponent:formconteningcomponent:component"`

`reRender` needs absolute path to component even if component id unique